# Question on possible Binomial Expirement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution

I have the following question:

> An interviewer is given a list of 8 people. Each person agrees to be interviewed with probability $2/3$. What is the probability that she will speak to exactly a) 6 people, b) 7 people?

I tried this problem by saying: Defind $X = $ the number of people who agree to be interviewed out of 8. So:
$$X = \mathcal{Binomial}(8,\frac{2}{3})$$

I want for part a:

$$P(X=6) = {^8\mathrm C_6}(2/3)^6(1/3)^2 = 1792/6561$$

and for part b:

$$P(X=7) = {^8\mathrm C_7}(2/3)^7(1/3)^1 = 1024/6561$$

Which according to the book is incorrect. The true answer, **for both parts** is $160/729$.

Any ideas or clues???

Comment: I guess you meant $P(X=6) = {}_8C_6(2/3)^6(1/3)^2$ and $P(X=7) = {}_8C_7(2/3)^7(1/3)^1$. Your answers seem right to me.

Comment: My apologies, fixed... But that is still strange as the key says it is incorrect

Comment: Unfortunately. It happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If she interviews exactly 6 people, then 6 will have said yes and 2 will have said no (independently). For each size-6 subset of 8 people, this occurs with probability $(2/3)^6 \cdot (1/3)^2$, and there are $\binom 86 = 28$ such subsets.

And if she interviews exactly 7, then 7 will have said yes and 1 will have said no. For each subset of size 7, this occurs with probability $(2/3)^7 \cdot (1/3)$, and there are $\binom 87 = 8$ such subsets. Thus
$$ \mathrm{Prob}(X = 6) = 28 \cdot (2/3)^6 \cdot (1/3)^2 = \dfrac{1792}{6561} \simeq 0.273 $$
and
$$ \mathrm{Prob}(X = 7) = 8 \cdot (2/3)^7 \cdot (1/3) = \dfrac{1024}{6561} \simeq 0.156 $$

Comment: Right, which is what I have in my attempted/suggested answer, but this is **not** correct for some reason. The real answer is supposedly $\frac{160}{729}$

Comment: The key seems to be incorrect, then. Your answer looks right.

Comment: the question itself is ambiguous. if you consider the phrase "she will speak to a person " to be equivalent to "she will interview a person", then this answer is correct. However, if you consider "she will speak to a person" to be equivalent to "she will ask to interview a person" then this answer is incorrect.